# segfault on vector assignment from two pointers

Tags: c++, memory-management, assign

I am trying to assign to a vector with the assign method, however the same code segfaults on my laptop but works on our computational cluster. The segfault originates from a call to assign like,

```
  double* val = mat.address_data();
  int* rp     = mat.address_major();
  int* cp     = mat.address_minor();
  // assign to the reserved location
  row_pointer_data.assign( rp,
                           rp+(m+1) );
  col_index_data.assign( cp,
                         cp+nz );
  value_data.assign( val,
                     val+nz );
```

where the mat is an MTL4 matrix giving pointers to its internal data with pointers to int and double. And these pointers point to blocks of nz doubles, m+1 integers and nz integers, respectively. I use intel c++ compiler on both environments and all the code is the same and for both shells, which is the bash shell, the stack sizes are unlimited.

However, col_index_data.assign() call gives a segmentation fault on my laptop and on the cluster it goes fine.

Using gdb or valgrind points to the same line which is related to, I guess an assembly command, _memmove_sse3(), used in the call to assign method, namely,

```
> #0  __memmove_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S:2928
> #1  0x000000000042df49 in VibroSys::read_triplet_data (mat=Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/utab/external_libraries/gdb_printers/python/mtl/printers.py",
> line 124, in to_string
>     A= empty_matrix(nr, nc)   File "/home/utab/external_libraries/gdb_printers/python/mtl/printers.py",
> line 38, in empty_matrix
>     return [copy.deepcopy(nr * ['0']) for c in range(nc)] MemoryError
> 
> , row_pointer_data=std::vector of length 19173284840251003, capacity
> 429530399489 = {...}, row_index_data=<error reading variable: Cannot
> access memory at address 0xa3bf88>, 
>     col_index_data=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x100008>, value_data=std::vector of length 0, capacity
> 4764228, col_indices_on_row=Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/utab/external_libraries/stl_printers/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py",
> line 427, in children
>     rep_type = find_type(self.val.type, '_Rep_type')   File "/home/utab/external_libraries/stl_printers/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py",
> line 43, in find_type
>     field = typ.fields()[0] IndexError: list index out of range
> 
> std::map with 25701680 elements, is_symmetric=false) at
> /home/utab/vibroSys/src/boost_matrix_utilities.cc:354
> #2  0x000000000042e172 in VibroSys::extract_sub_matrix (input_matrix=Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/utab/external_libraries/gdb_printers/python/mtl/printers.py",
> line 124, in to_string
>     A= empty_matrix(nr, nc)   File "/home/utab/external_libraries/gdb_printers/python/mtl/printers.py",
> line 38, in empty_matrix
>     return [copy.deepcopy(nr * ['0']) for c in range(nc)] MemoryError
> 
> , sub_index1=std::vector of length 19173284840251003, capacity
> 429530399489 = {...}, sub_index2=<error reading variable: Cannot
> access memory at address 0xa3bf88>, sub_matrix=
>     <error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x100000>) at /home/utab/vibroSys/src/boost_matrix_utilities.cc:995
> #3  0x000000000040f93a in main (argc=36433120, argv=0xa3c000) at timing_test.cc:145
```

What could be the reason of these two different behaviour for the same code in two different environments?

Comment: Is it possible any of those methods return `NULL`? Or the `+nz` goes beyond the end of an array?

Comment: Run it under `valgrind`.

Comment: you mean the methods of the mat right? apparently, there is an access violation. I checked out exactly the same code from the repository to be sure of what I am doing and that is the point that puzzles me...

Comment: Is mat a compressed2D matrix?

Comment: Yes it is a compressed2D matrix

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty common to find faults when compiling on a second architecture.  Consider a buffer overflow: if it doesn't have negative consequences (eg, overwrite something important, or go out-of-bounds and seg fault), you probably won't notice it exists.  Then on another machine, the executable is arranged some what differently, and the overflow does have negative consequences, so you notice it.

Ie, you have a bug.  The fact that it shows up in one place but not in another sometimes does not mean it is not a bug everywhere, period, with *potentially* negative consequences.

Comment: Indeed, I am aware of it now, I could not find the cure yet though ;-)

Comment: Well, you probably didn't post enough code for anyone else to find it. Eg, the value of `m` is not clear.  I haven't used MTL, but what do those functions do? Did you write them? Etc.